# Trigger event with infoWindow or InfoBox on click Google Map API V3

Tags: google-maps-api-3, infowindow, infobox

I want to know how to trigger an event when I click on an infoWindow using Google Maps API v3.  In this example, when I click on a marker, an info window shows up with a unique message, based on which marker I clicked.  I want to also be able to click the info window and have an alert show up that says

> "You clicked on the infowindow for (**__*fill in blank location*_**)

I found some examples using Google Maps API v2 and jQuery, but not with just plain old Google Maps API v3.

```js
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>jQuery mobile with Google maps - Google maps jQuery plugin</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.0.1/jquery.mobile-1.0.1.min.css" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.6.4.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.0.1/jquery.mobile-1.0.1.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?v=3&sensor=false&language=en"> </script>
    <script type="text/javascript">

    var cityList = [
    ['Chicago', 41.850033, -87.6500523, 1],
    ['Illinois', 40.797177,-89.406738, 2]
    ];

    var demoCenter = new google.maps.LatLng(41,-87);

    var map;
    function initialize()
    {
        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_canvas'), {
            zoom: 7,
            center: demoCenter,
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        });
        addMarkers();
    }

    function addMarkers()
    {
        var marker, i;
        var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
        for (i = 0; i < cityList.length; i++)
        {
            marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: new google.maps.LatLng(cityList[i][1], cityList[i][2]),
                map: map,
                title: cityList[i][0]
            });

            google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, i) {
                var contentString = '<div id="infoWindow">'
                    +'<div id="bodyContent">'
                    +'<p>'
                    + "This location is:<br>"
                    + marker.title
                    +'</p>'
                    +'</div>'
                    + '</div>';
                return function() {
                    infowindow.setContent(contentString);
                    infowindow.open(map, marker);
                    google.maps.event.addListener(infowindow, 'click', (function(i){
                        alert("You clicked on the infowindow for" + cityList[i][0]);
                    }));
                }
                })(marker, i));
            }
        }

</script>
    </head>
    <body onload="initialize()">
        <div id="basic-map" data-role="page">
            <div data-role="header">
                <h1><a data-ajax="false" href="/">jQuery mobile with Google maps v3</a> examples</h1>
                <a data-rel="back">Back</a>
            </div>
            <div data-role="content">
                <div class="ui-bar-c ui-corner-all ui-shadow" style="padding:1em;">
                    <div id="map_canvas" style="height:350px;"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

**Update** I ended up figuring this out for InfoBox as well, which is included below in my answer.

Comment: You might be interested in using snazzy-info-window as an alternative.

https://github.com/atmist/snazzy-info-window/blob/master/examples/dynamic-content/scripts.js

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Ok I figured this out for `infoWindow`, but then I also figured it out for `InfoBox` since it is prettier and more customizable. I'm new to JavaScript and these closures can be very tricky.

**For `infoWindow`**

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>jQuery mobile with Google maps - Google maps jQuery plugin</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.0.1/jquery.mobile-1.0.1.min.css" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.6.4.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.0.1/jquery.mobile-1.0.1.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?v=3&sensor=false&language=en"> </script>
    <script type="text/javascript">

    var cityList = [
    ['Chicago', 41.850033, -87.6500523, 1],
    ['Illinois', 40.797177,-89.406738, 2]
    ];

    var demoCenter = new google.maps.LatLng(41,-87);

    var map;
    function initialize()
    {
        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_canvas'), {
            zoom: 7,
            center: demoCenter,
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        });
        addMarkers();
    }

    var boxText1 = document.createElement("div");
            boxText1.id = "boxText1";
            boxText1.className = "labelText1";
            boxText1.innerHTML = "title1";//this is created earlier 
    var boxList = [];

    function addMarkers()
    {
        var marker, i;
        var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
            disableAutoPan: true
          ,isHidden:false
          ,pixelOffset: new google.maps.Size(-10, -10)
          ,closeBoxURL: ""
          ,pane: "mapPane"
          ,enableEventPropagation: true
        });
        for (var i = 0; i < cityList.length; i++)
        {
            marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: new google.maps.LatLng(cityList[i][1], cityList[i][2]),
                map: map,
                id: i,
                title: cityList[i][0]
            });

            var boxText = document.createElement("div");
            boxText.id = i;
            boxText.className = "labelText" + i;
            boxText.innerHTML = cityList[i][0];
            boxList.push(boxText);

            google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, i) {
                var contentString = '<div id="infoWindow">'
                    +'<div id="bodyContent">'
                    +'<p>'
                    + "This location is:<br>"
                    + marker.title
                    +'</p>'
                    +'</div>'
                    + '</div>';

                return function() {
                    infowindow.setContent(boxList[this.id]);
                    infowindow.open(map, marker);
                }
                })(marker, i)); //end add marker listener

                google.maps.event.addDomListener(boxList[i],'click',(function(marker, i) {
                        return function() {
                          alert('clicked ' + cityList[i][0])
                        }
                      })(marker, i));
            } //endfor              
        }//end function

</script>
    </head>
    <body onload="initialize()">
        <div id="basic-map" data-role="page">
            <div data-role="header">
                <h1><a data-ajax="false" href="/">jQuery mobile with Google maps v3</a> examples</h1>
                <a data-rel="back">Back</a>
            </div>
            <div data-role="content">
                <div class="ui-bar-c ui-corner-all ui-shadow" style="padding:1em;">
                    <div id="map_canvas" style="height:350px;"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

**For `InfoBox`**

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>jQuery mobile with Google maps - Google maps jQuery plugin</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.0.1/jquery.mobile-1.0.1.min.css" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.6.4.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.0.1/jquery.mobile-1.0.1.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?v=3&sensor=false&language=en"> </script>
    <script type="text/javascript"
    src="http://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/infobox/src/infobox.js"> </script>
    <script type="text/javascript"
    src="http://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/infobox/src/infobox_packed.js"> </script>
    <script type="text/javascript">

    var cityList = [
    ['Chicago', 41.850033, -87.6500523, 1],
    ['Illinois', 40.797177,-89.406738, 2]
    ];

    var demoCenter = new google.maps.LatLng(41,-87);
    var boxList =[];

    function initialize() {
        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_canvas'), {
            zoom: 7,
            center: demoCenter,
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        });
        addMarkers();
    }

    function addMarkers(){
        for (var i = 0; i < cityList.length; i++)
        {
            marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: new google.maps.LatLng(cityList[i][1], cityList[i][2]),
                map: map,
                id: i,
                title: cityList[i][0]
            });         

            var boxText = document.createElement("div");
            boxText.id = i;
            boxText.style.cssText = "border: 1px solid black; margin-top: 8px; background: yellow; padding: 5px;";
            boxText.innerHTML = "InfoBox for " + cityList[i][0];

            var myOptions = {
                content: boxText
                ,disableAutoPan: false
                ,maxWidth: 0
                ,pixelOffset: new google.maps.Size(-140, 0)
                ,zIndex: null
                ,boxStyle: {
                    background: "url('tipbox.gif') no-repeat"
                    ,opacity: 0.75
                    ,width: "280px"
                }
                ,closeBoxMargin: "10px 2px 2px 2px"
                ,closeBoxURL: "http://www.google.com/intl/en_us/mapfiles/close.gif"
                ,infoBoxClearance: new google.maps.Size(1, 1)
                ,isHidden: false
                ,pane: "floatPane"
                ,enableEventPropagation: false
            };

            var ib = new InfoBox(myOptions);
            boxList.push(ib);

            google.maps.event.addListener(marker,'click',(function(marker, i) {
                return function() {
                    boxList[i].open(map, this);
                }
            })(marker, i));

            google.maps.event.addDomListener(boxList[i].content_,'click',(function(marker, i) {
                    return function() {
                      alert('clicked ' + cityList[i][0])
                    }
                  })(marker, i));
        } //endfor  
    } //end function

    </script>
</head>
<body onload="initialize()">
    <div id="basic-map" data-role="page">
        <div data-role="header">
            <h1><a data-ajax="false" href="/">jQuery mobile with Google maps v3</a> examples</h1>
            <a data-rel="back">Back</a>
        </div>
        <div data-role="content">
            <div class="ui-bar-c ui-corner-all ui-shadow" style="padding:1em;">
                <div id="map_canvas" style="height:350px;"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: If I perform click function on Infobox it's invoking click function in marker. Could you please help to resolve the issue. Please add alert in marker click to debug the issue.

Comment: The code I wrote works like this: one click of a marker opens and Infobox, then, once the Infobox is open, if you click that you get an alert.  Are you trying to do something different than this?

Comment: I am doing same mentioned by you , but your code is working fine in Android as mentioned by you. But I am getting issues only in iOS. In iOS for second click on Infobox only opens alert because first click is triggering marker click.

Comment: Hi, I´m trying to make your example work in a plunker, but it´s not working. Do you know why? https://plnkr.co/edit/cRdiu6QkZsnDoZBRM1sJ?p=preview

Answer (score 14):

The InfoWindow object does not have a 'click' event, so you cannot do

```
google.maps.event.addListener(infowindow, 'click',....
```

instead, you can attach an event handler to the DOM object, such as

```
function addMarker(latLng, name){

var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    map:map,
    position:latLng
});

G.event.addListener(marker,'click',function(mev){
        var div = document.createElement('div');
        div.innerHTML = name;
        div.onclick = function(){iwClick(name)};
        infoWindow.setContent(div);
        infoWindow.setPosition(mev.latLng);
        infoWindow.open(map);

    });
}

function iwClick(str){
    alert(str);
};
```

and you call it with

```
var chicago = new google.maps.LatLng(41.850033, -87.6500523);
addMarker(chicago,'chicago');
```

Comment: What is that **G** stand for ?

Comment: window.google.maps

Answer (score 2):

Inorder to make an infowindow clickable or you want fire a function on click of any tags inside the infowindow, the dom has to be ready. So when the dom is ready you can call a function.

```js
google.maps.event.addListener(infowindow, 'domready', function() {
            document.getElementById('yourId').addEventListener("click", yourFucntionToCall);
            function yourFucntionToCall() {
              Your fucntion code......
            }
          });
```

Answer (score 1):

Thanx! Erin is tha man! You fixed my problem! I was bashing it for 4 days now! Closures are a pain in the *** if you are new to them.

Here's is my working code (Sencha Touch 2 and Google maps API v3). It will oly allow one infowindow to be open.

```
var openedInfoWindow = null;
var boxList = [];
var marker, i;

//build info box object
var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
    enableEventPropagation: true,
});

//handle close
google.maps.event.addListener(infoWindow, 'closeclick', function() {
    openedInfoWindow = null;
});

//loop trough store data...
for(i in data) {
    //data
    var itemData = data[i].getData();

    //marker
    var geopos = new google.maps.LatLng(itemData['lat'], itemData['lng']);
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: geopos,
        //icon: image,
        map: map,
        title: itemData['title'],
        id: i,
        animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP
    });

    //add info window content to DOM
    var boxText = document.createElement("div");
    boxText.id = i;
    boxText.className = "labelText" + i;
    boxText.data = itemData;
    boxText.innerHTML = '<b>' + itemData['title'] + '</b>' + (itemData['distance'] ? ' (' + itemData['distance'] + ')' : '') + '<br />' + (itemData['address'] != itemData['title'] ? itemData['address'] : '') + (itemData['price'] ? '<br />' + itemData['price'] : '') + '<br /><a class="button">Meer info</a>';
    boxList.push(boxText);

    //add marker click event
    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, i) {
        if (openedInfoWindow != null)
            openedInfoWindow.close();

        return function() {
            infoWindow.setContent(boxList[this.id]);
            infoWindow.open(map, marker);
            openedInfoWindow = infoWindow;
        }
    })(marker, i));

    //when infowindow is clicked, open view...
    google.maps.event.addDomListener(boxList[i],'click',(function(marker, i) {
        return function(){
            iStuddy.app.pushView('kames_detail',boxList[i].data);
        }
    })(marker, i));
}
```

Comment: I couldn't found any documentation about `enableEventPropagation` on [infoWindow object specification](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#InfoWindowOptions) (version 3.24)

Answer (score 0):

my solution:
try use onClick in xml

```
<InfoWindow  onCloseClick={props.onToggleOpen}>
     <div onClick={()=>{alert('hello')}} class="wow slideInLeft">
        <img src="https://i.imgur.com/7IgBxnH.jpg" width="150px" />
        <div>nhà trọ cho thuê</div>
         <div>1.500.000đ</div>
     </div>
 </InfoWindow>
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all your comments. I manage to build (after reading your suggestions) an example that works without modifying the **Infowindow** code.

The **infoWindow** itself should only contain a placeholder div with a unique **id**:

```
    <InfoWindow
        marker={this.state.activeMarker}
        visible={this.state.showingInfoWindow}
        onOpen={e => {
          this.onInfoWindowOpen(this.props, e);
        }}
      >
        <div id="xyz" />
      </InfoWindow>
```

And inside the **Mapcontainer**, you define an onInfoWindowOpen callback, that inserts a single component/container with the onClick event and render it to a placeholder **div**:

```
    onInfoWindowOpen = () => {
        const button = (<button 
        onClick={
            () => {
            this.viewClinic(this.state.selectedPlace.slug)
            }
            }>
            View Details
        </button>);
        ReactDOM.render(React.Children.only(button),document.getElementById("xyz"));
        }
```

---

**Here is a working example:**

### https://codesandbox.io/s/k0xrxok983

---

One more complete example **MAP**, **Marker** and **InfoWindow**:

### https://codesandbox.io/s/24m1yrr4mj