# Is InfoWindow in javascript is clickable or not for mobile devices?

Tags: javascript, jquery-mobile, google-maps-mobile

I have a location in my app, when I click on button, it will show me a map with marker on that location, when I click on marker it shows me a InfoWindow with details of that location. Now I want that when I click on that InfoWindow, another map page is open showing path between my current location and that location.

Is anybody suggest me that Is InfoWindow is clickable or not in mobile devices, so I move on next page.

Any help is appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why don't you just try it yourself and see?

Comment: I have finish everything but dont get anything about clickable InfoWindow.

Answer (score 0):

It cant be done like that.

You have 3 other options:

1. Look at [this](http://jquery-ui-map.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/demos/jquery-google-maps-streetview.html) example and replace infoWindow with dialog box:
2. Place click event on marker a display needed info on the another page:

   ```
   $('#map_canvas').gmap('addMarker', {
        'position': new google.maps.LatLng(parameters[j].lat, parameters[j].lng),
        'bounds': true
   }).click(function() {
         // Do something with marker
   });
   ```
3. In case of google.maps.Map implementation there is a plugin used to create custom info box. It is called InfoBox, [here](http://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/infobox/docs/examples.html) and [here](http://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/infobox/docs/reference.html) you can find more about it. Style it as much as you want.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12102598/trigger-event-with-infowindow-or-infobox-on-click-google-map-api-v3) you will find an example how to add click event on infoWindow and infoBox (v2 and v3). After that just use this code to show a page you want:

```
$.mobile.changePage("#jobInfo", {transition: "none", reloadPage : false});
```

Comment: First option is not so good for mobile devices and in my app I am not using gmap. So is there any another way to solve this. Thanks

Comment: Which map implementation are you using?

Comment: map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_canvas'),
        myOptions); I use this.

Comment: Excellent, I have added a 3rd option, this one is built for your map implementation.

Comment: Thanks for the help,but in this example, it will create InfoBox, but I want that InfoBox is clicked and redirect to next page. var ib = new InfoBox(myOptions);
        ib.open(theMap, marker);this is already done by me.

Comment: Take a look now, I have added a link to the example how to do it. I don't have time to test it myself.

Comment: Thanku so much, may be its helpful for me.