# Registering click event on Google Maps Infowindow

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers

I am building a hotel website and working on the map to show hotels. 
[image]
I am using a mix of AngularJS code and the example codes provided by Google Maps Javascript API ( https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/infowindow-simple).

My code goes as below -

```
    function initMap() {
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
          zoom: 12,
          center: coord
        });

        $http.post("/events/hotel_search", { city : city, facilities : facilities }).then(function(response) {
            $scope.hotels = response.data.hotels;
var image = '/img/bed.png';
$scope.hotels.forEach(function(h){

      var contentString= '<div style="width:350px"><div style="width:130px;float:left"><img src="'+h.images[0]+'"  width="130" /><h4>'+h.name+'</h4></div><div style="width:200px;float:left;padding-left:20px"><p style="font-size:150%;color:orange">200-500$/night</p><p style="font-size:80%">'+h.address+'</p><div class="star-rating-r"><a href="#"><img alt="" src="img/rating-b.png"></a><a href="#"><img alt="" src="img/rating-b.png"></a><a href="#"><img alt="" src="img/rating-b.png"></a><a href="#"><img alt="" src="img/rating-b.png"></a><a href="#"><img alt="" src="img/rating-a.png"></a></div><p><br/><div class="cat-icons"><span class="cat-icon-01 active"></span><span class="cat-icon-02"></span><span class="cat-icon-03"></span><span class="cat-icon-04"></span><span class="cat-icon-05"></span><span class="cat-icon-06"></span><div class="clear"></div></div></p><button class="srch-btn xbtn" style="margin-top:20px;float:right" id="'+h._id+'">SELECT HOTEL</button></div></div>';



        var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
            content: contentString
          });
            var beachMarker = new google.maps.Marker({
              position: {lat: h.lat, lng: h.lng },
              map: map,
              icon: image
            });

          beachMarker.addListener('click', function() {
            infowindow.open(map, beachMarker);
          });





   })


     });

      }
```

My problem is that I am failing to register a click event when someone clicks on the button inside the infowindow. I am referring to the 'SELECT HOTEL' button. How do I go about this ?

Comment: `<button class="srch-btn xbtn" style="margin-top:20px;float:right" id="'+h._id+'" ng-click="doSomething()">SELECT HOTEL</button>`. Tried something similar?

Comment: @theblindprophet - Yes, tried similar. Doesnt work.  ng-click doesnt work because I guess these DOM elements are inserted after the page loads. Simple non angular onclick="do_something()" works though.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12102598/trigger-event-with-infowindow-or-infobox-on-click-google-map-api-v3