# How can add click event into google map infowindow in javascript

Tags: javascript, google-maps

Does anyone know how can add click event into google map info window in javascript?
I want to be able to get click event from popup info window.
Is this possible or not ?

Comment: Yes it is possible.Write you google map code where you are rendering the infowindow he i will  edit your answer

Comment: duplicate question : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12102598/trigger-event-with-infowindow-or-infobox-on-click-google-map-api-v3

Answer (score 7):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script
src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js">
</script>

<script>
var myCenter=new google.maps.LatLng(51.508742,-0.120850);

function initialize()
{
var mapProp = {
  center:myCenter,
  zoom:5,
  mapTypeId:google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  };

var map=new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("googleMap"),mapProp);

var marker=new google.maps.Marker({
  position:myCenter,
  });

marker.setMap(map);

var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
  content:"<button onclick='xyz()'>abcd</button>"
  });

google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
  infowindow.open(map,marker);
  });
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);

function xyz(){
alert('Hello')
}
</script>
</head>

<body>
<div id="googleMap" style="width:500px;height:380px;"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Please check this will work for you

Comment: Thanks, as I understand we only can add the button on the popup window and get button click event, other solutions are not.?

Comment: @Developer It doesn't need to be a button. You can use any element you want. You just give it onclick handler like in the example.