# Ionic 2 - Push a new page when I click on a google maps info window

Tags: javascript, api, google-maps, ionic2

I'm using the google maps api in my ionic 2 project. I have a service for creating the markers and cluster them. I'm creating a info window for each marker like this:

```
content = "<h4>Title</h4><p onclick=\"callFunctionFromServiceHere()\">Go to new page</p>";
var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
    content: content
});
```

I want to push a new page if I click on "Go to new page". How is that possible? Because I think the HTML of the info windows does not have access to my ionic 2 service.

Comment: Please see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43128921/custom-google-maps-infowindow-using-ionic-2/43181306#43181306) solution. This solution should help you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can add an `eventListener` to catch a click on your infowindow.

Here for example :

```
google.maps.event.addListener(infoWindow, 'domready', () => {
  //now my elements are ready for dom manipulation
  var clickableItem = document.getElementById('clickableItem');
  clickableItem.addEventListener('click', () => {
    this.goToProductPage(product);
  });
});
```

You just have to add another Listener to wait until the dom is ready, otherwise your elements will not be ready for dom manipulation..

Here some more [infos](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43321635/click-on-infowindow-typescript-angular2/43349140#43349140),

Hope it helped you ;)